# MUI 5 style override when using multiple themes

Tags: material-ui, themes

I have 2 MUI5 themes that I have created. One is a light theme which has styles for various MUI components. I have a dark theme that uses the light theme as its base and only has the dark colors defined in it. So base styles for all components are coming from the light theme, and dark theme only has new color palette defined. I have the following styles for a button in light theme.

```
MuiButton: {
    defaultProps: {
        variant: 'outlined',
        disableRipple: true,
    },
    styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
            borderRadius: '2rem',
            boxShadow: 'none',
            '&:focus': {
                outlineOffset: `0`,
                outline: `2px solid lightBlue`,
                boxShadow: 'none',
            },
        }),
    }, 
    ...
}
```

I want to define a different color for the button outline in the dark theme. How do I do this without repeating the entire MuiButton declaration in the dark theme?

If I declare only the changed focus style in the dark theme (as shown), it is taking all the styles for the button  from the default Mui theme and ignoring the button styles I have declared in the light theme. What is the best work around for this without having to repeat all of the MuiButton styles in both the themes?

```
MuiButton: {
    styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
            '&:focus': {
                outline: `2px solid darkBlue`,
            },
        }),
    }, 
}
```